# $(W^\perp)^\perp$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $\langle , \rangle$ be a scalar product on a vector space $V$ over a field $K$. I wanted to know what can we say about $(W^\perp)^\perp$ with $W$ a subspace of $V$.
I heard that if the field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, and if $W$ is a Hilbert space (I don't know what it is) then $(W^\perp)^\perp = \overline{W}$.
What can we say in general ? When $K=\mathbb R$, do we have $(W^\perp)^\perp \subseteq W$ or maybe $(W^\perp)^\perp \supseteq W$ for any $\mathbb R$-vector space W ?

Comment: the fact you stated about hilbert space should tell you the first containment isn't true in general. the second containment is true just by symmetry of orthogonality

Comment: Just take a non closed $W$ and see what happens.

Comment: I must admit I struggle to find counterexamples for the first inclusion, can you give me some ? @Timkinsella